# "Continuous composition" of Lie Bracket

Tags: limits, lie-algebras, matrix-calculus, function-and-relation-composition

Let $A,X\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$. We denote $[A,X]=AX-XA$ the commutator. It is indeed a Lie Bracket for the matrix Lie algebra.

Taking $A$ constant, I'm looking for "the flow" of the commutator. That is to say, a "natural" function $\Phi([A,\cdot{}],t)$ with $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that if $t=n\in\mathbb{N}$:

$$\Phi([A,\cdot{}],n)(X) = [A,\;\dots\;[A, [A,X]]\dots\;]=[(A)^n,X]$$

If such a function exists, is there a "good" way to "extend it" for a matrix $A$ changing continuously as the composition goes on ? That is, for $A:t\mapsto A(t)\in \mathcal{C}([t_0,t_f],M_n(\mathbb{R}))$ being a continuous function.

To sum up my question:

For $A$ constant:
$$\Phi([A,\cdot{}],t)(X) = [(A)^t,X]=\;?$$

And for a continuous matrix $A$:
$$\left(\mathop{\bigcirc}\limits_{t_0}^{t}\Phi([A(s),\cdot{}],ds)\right)(X)=\left(\mathop{\bigcirc}\limits_{t_0}^{t}[(A(s))^{ds},\cdot]\right)(X)=\;?$$

Thank you in advance for your kind help.

**EDIT:** Here is my main idea for the constant case so far:

First let's distinguish the exponential of a function and the exponential of a matrix:

$$\begin{aligned}\exp(f)&=Id+f+\frac{1}{2!}f\circ f+\frac{1}{3!}f\circ f\circ f+...\\e^{M}&=I_n+M+\frac{1}{2!}M^2+\frac{1}{3!}M^3+...\end{aligned}$$

It is known that $\exp([A,\cdot{}])=e^{A}\times\cdot{}\times e^{-A}$, by which I mean that for all $X\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, we have $\exp([A,\cdot{}])(X)=e^{A}Xe^{-A}$. Hence:

$$\Phi(\exp([A,\cdot{}]),t)=\Phi(e^{A}\times\cdot{}\times e^{-A},t)=e^{tA}\times\cdot{}\times e^{-tA}$$

Now, one can imagine that:

$$\exp(\Phi([A,\cdot{}],t))=\Phi(\exp([A,\cdot{}]),t)$$

If one manages to show the above property and to extend the $\log$ operation to functions (when does it converge ?), we should obtain at the end:

$$\begin{aligned}\Phi([A,\cdot{}],t)&= \log(\exp(\Phi([A,\cdot{}],t))) \\
&=\log(\Phi(\exp([A,\cdot{}]),t))\\
&=\log(\Phi(e^{A}\times \cdot{}\times e^{-A},t))\\
&=\log (e^{tA}\times \cdot{} \times e^{-tA}) \\
&=\;?
\end{aligned}$$

**BUT**, this approach might be very wrong, since we have:
$$\Phi(\exp([A,\cdot{}]),t)=e^{tA}\times\cdot{}\times e^{-tA}=\exp([tA,\cdot{}])$$
and unfortunately I think we are faced with:
$$\exp([tA,\cdot{}]) \neq\exp(\Phi([A,\cdot{}],t))$$

I would also like to extend the previous result to a more general setting where $f$ denotes a function taken without a lot of hypothesis:

$$\Phi(\exp{f},t)=\exp(t\times f)$$

Any reference or homemade proof on this matter would be very much appreciated: I will be happy to grant the bounty just for this result. I believe it can be useful for the non-constant case, if we get there at some point...

Comment: Do you know the answer when A is constant?

Comment: No, I'm working on it using Schröder's functional equation but it is far from trivial and I'm not even sure this is a correct approach

Comment: You don't know whether $A$ is differentiable?

Comment: I don't see a problem assuming it if it helps !

Comment: Problems might arise even when $A$ is constant. Let for example $\sigma_x,\sigma_y,\sigma_z$ be the [Pauli matrices](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pauli_matrices) and take $A\equiv\frac12\sigma_x$ and $X=\frac12\sigma_y.$ Then $[A(t_0), X]=i\sigma_z,$ $[A(t_0+\epsilon), [A(t_0), X]]=\sigma_y,$ $[A(t_0+2\epsilon), [A(t_0+\epsilon), [A(t_0), X]]]=i\sigma_z, \ldots$ so there is no convergence.

Comment: True, another example of this behavior (assuming $A$ constant) is simply $[A,...[A,X]]=[(A)^n,X]=\sum_{k=0}^{n}(-1)^kA^{n-k}XA^k$ (if I'm not mistaken) which is also alternating because of the $(-1)^k$...
But I guess my question is more about the "flow" of the commutator itself, ie find a continuous function $\Phi(X,A,t)$ with $t\in\mathbb{R}$ such that when $t=n\in\mathbb{N}$, $\Phi(X,A,n)=[(A)^n,X]$. And is there a "good" way to extend this function for a matric A changing continuously as the composition goes on ?

Comment: For constant $A$ and $n$ a natural number, $\Phi(A,n)(X)$, up to some factorials and other constants you can add, some of the coefficients in the Baker-Campbell-Hausdorff formula for $\log(e^Ae^X)$. Perhaps this can be of some help. (Also, in this light it is not surprising that convergence issues appear, as they also appear in the B-C-H formula).

Comment: it was indeed while learning about the B-C-H formula that I asked myself this question... in fact I kind of already have the following intuition in the constant case. One might be able to "take the log" of $\Phi(\exp([A,\cdot{}]),t)$, with $\exp(f)=Id+f+\frac{1}{2!}f\circ f +\frac{1}{3!}f\circ f\circ f+... $ , using the fact that $\exp([A,\cdot{}])=e^{A}\cdot{}e^{-A} $. But I find myself having a hard time formalizing it

Answer (score 0):

I would argue that finding a "natural way" to define such object it is a lost cause in most cases even when the matrix is taken to be constant:

Consider $A\in M_n(\mathbb{R})$, $\operatorname{ad}_A:=[A,\cdot]$ is an element of $\mathfrak{gl}(M_n(\mathbb{R}))$. As such it can be respresented as an element of $M_{n^2}(\mathbb{R})$ say $\tilde{A}$. The morphism $\operatorname{ad}_A^n$ is then given by taking the $n^{th}$ power of $\tilde{A}$ for $n\in\mathbb{N}$. In this context, extending the construction to the real in a "natural way" of  would amount to define $\tilde{A}^t$ for $t\in\mathbb{R}$.

This is fine when $\tilde{A}$ is diagonalizable whith stricly positive eigenvalues say $\tilde{A}=PDP^{-1}$ whith $P$ invertible and $D$ diagonal. One could set $\tilde{A}^t=PD^tP^{-1}$ with $D^t$ being the diagonal matrix whose elements on the diagonal are the one of $D$ raised to the power $t$. In this construction stricly positive eigenvalues are needed when $t$ is negative.

My point is that taking an arbitrary matrix to a real power (or even a positive rational one) has no good definition to my knowledge.

PS : A small result from Lie algebra theory is that (over $\mathbb{C}$) $\tilde{A}$ is diagonalizable iif $A$ is diagonalizable.